# Sized box vs padding for distances in columns and rows

Tags: flutter

Is there a performance difference between `SizedBox` and `Padding` when applying distance inside Column and Row.

Here is an example:

```
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            ProfileAvatar(
              photoUrl: vo.photoUrl,
              height: 90.0,
            ),
```

or this

```
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
            ),
            ProfileAvatar(
              photoUrl: vo.photoUrl,
              height: 90.0,
            ),
```

Which one should be preferred, or recommended by the flutter team?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`SizedBox` win. As it only applies constraints to it's child.

But considering they both don't have a child, they do the same thing litteraly. At most you'll have a nanosecond worth of difference/ 
That is especially true considering both syntaxes  in your example will be instantiated as "const". Which abort the following rebuild.

Use whatever fits you the best. The gain is so minimal you'll never ever notice a difference. So take what is clearer

Comment: I still don't understand why `SizedBox` wins based on your answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: In this scenario, I don't think there could be anything more imperative

Answer (score 14):

I think `SizedBox` make code easier to read by flatten nested lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

As Remi said, it does not really matter in your case, but if you decide to adjust only single or combination of left, right, top or bottom offsets, then wrapping a widget with Padding makes more sense.

Padding insets its child (adds an empty space to edges of its child without extending the child).

SizedBox creates a fixed size box, and its child will extend to the specified width and height.